# SELECT from two tables WHERE different columns in each table equal $id ORDER BY common column (PHP/MySQL)

Tags: php, mysql, multiple-tables

I'm trying to SELECT from two tables and ORDER BY date (a column they both have). One table (tableA) has a column called "A" and the other table (tableB) has a column called "B", I use array_key_exists() to differentiate between the two (If "A" key exists, I run the array through FunctionA(), if "B" key exists, I run the array through FunctionB()). I only need the 20 latest (date wise) entries. I need the SQL Query to accomplish this.

I already know a reply will be "if they're similarly structured, then you should just use a single table", but I don't want to do that because tableA is drastically different from tableB (a lot more columns in tableA), and using a single table to store the data would result in a LOT of empty columns for entries formatted for tableB, not to mention it'd be a very ugly looking table format due to tableB not needing the majority of tableA's columns).

I just want to display data from both tables in an ordered (by date) fashion, and in one single stream.

I need to SELECT WHERE tableA.poster_id = $id and tableB.receiver_id = $id by the way.

SOLUTION:

I'm updating this just in case anyone else with the same dilemma comes along.  After implementing the SQL query that @Erik A. Brandstadmoen had graciously given me, this is basically what my code ended up as:

```
$MySQL->SQL("SELECT * FROM
              (SELECT A.id AS id, A.date AS date, 'tableA' AS source 
                 FROM tableA A WHERE A.poster_id = $id 
                    UNION
                      SELECT B.id AS id, B.date AS date, 'tableB' AS source
                           FROM tableB B WHERE B.receiver_id = $id) AS T
                               ORDER BY T.date DESC LIMIT 0, 20");

$GetStream = array();
$i = 0;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($MySQL->Result))
{
    $GetStream[$i]['id'] = $row['id'];
    $GetStream[$i]['date']=$row['date'];
    $GetStream[$i]['source'] = $row['source'];
    $i++;
}

*** later on down the code ***

$i = 0;
while ($i<count($GetStream))
{
    if ($GetStream[$i]['source'] == "tableA")
    { 
        FunctionA($GetStream[$i]);
    }
    else
    {
        FunctionB($GetStream[$i]);
    }
    $i++;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `UNION`:

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT A.col1 AS x, A.col2 As y, A.col3 AS date FROM tableA A
WHERE tableA.poster_id = $id
UNION 
SELECT B.colA AS x, B.colB AS y, B.colC AS date FROM  tableB B
WHERE tableB.receiver_id = $id
)
ORDER BY date DESC
LIMIT 0, 20
```

OR, IF you would like to keep duplicates between tableA and tableB, use `UNION ALL` instead.

EDIT, according to your comments, I understand that you need a column indicating which table the row is from. You can just add a static column in the select, like this:

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT A.col1 AS x, A.col2 As y, A.col3 AS date, 'A' as source FROM tableA A
WHERE tableA.poster_id = $id
UNION 
SELECT B.colA AS x, B.colB AS y, B.colC AS date, 'B' as source FROM  tableB B
WHERE tableB.receiver_id = $id
)
ORDER BY date DESC
LIMIT 0, 20
```

This gives you a nice table on the following form:

```
x    y    date    source
=========================
(v1) (v2) (d1)    'A'
(v3) (v4) (d2)    'B'
(v1) (v2) (d3)    'B'
(v3) (v4) (d4)    'A'
```

That does what you want, doesn't it? It's a bit difficult understanding what you are really trying to achieve with this...

Comment: Keep in mind that with a UNION, the number/names of columns have to be the same between both SELECT's (hence aliasing "as x", "as y", etc. in this both selects in Erik's queries.)

Comment: I just tried:
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT A.id AS x, A.A AS y, A.date AS date FROM tableA A
WHERE A.poster_id = $id
UNION 
SELECT B.id AS x, B.B AS y, B.date AS date FROM  tableB B
WHERE B.receiver_id = $id
) AS T
ORDER BY date DESC
LIMIT 0, 20

But it's still returning things out of order, thank you for the reply by the way.

Comment: UNION is definitely the method you want to use in this situation.  You shouldn't need the first SELECT * FROM() this could be causing a problem with the order by but I'm not sure.

Comment: After messing with it a little, I've gotten it to order by date, BUT, for some reason column B is being saved under column A, so I can't differentiate between the two types, thanks a ton for the help, almost there.

Comment: @Caimen: If you don't do the outer select, you will get table A sorted by date, and then table B sorted by date appended to it. The total set will not be sorted by date.

Comment: @Lamoni: What do you mean "Column B is being saved under column A"? Do you have a column called A in tableA and a table called B in tableB too? Ayway, I don't understand what you mean by "column B being saved under column A". If you mean all the values end up in one column, that is kind of the point. If you want columns from tableA and tableB to end up in different columns in the result set, you need to do an outer join of the tables.

Comment: Would it be sloppy style to just make a new boolean column called "type", and then if it's false, run it through FunctionA, and if it's true, run it through FunctionB? Since the query (modified from your example above) is returning the correct rows and the correct date order but with the wrong column name (tableB's data is still being saved with the key "A", so I can't differentiate between the two). That way it doesn't matter that they're being returned with the same column name, because I can check the value. (So basically I'd be using A.type and B.type rather than A.A and B.B).

Comment: @Erik A. Brandstadmoen oh yes of course, i misinterpreted the question.

Comment: @Erik, yes I need it to be separate. The existence of "A" key determines which function I run the array through.  If all the data being returned is using the "A" key, I can't differentiate which data is from tableA and which data is from tableB. In short, I need tableA results to keep the key A, and tableB results to keep the key B.

Comment: (I apologize for the confusing way I attempt to explain things, I'm not well versed with database nomenclature).

Comment: see my edit in my answer. Will that do what you want? If not, could you give an example of the data you want to return from your select (a table giving example expected outputs), and I will try to adjust the query... :)

Comment: Perfect! Thank you, worked like a charm.  The source was EXACTLY what I needed.  Also as a bonus, I could remove my array_key_exists() calls. Thank you for your time, marking as answered.

Comment: Exactly what I thought... :) Good luck onwards with your project!